# How can I efficiently extract hours and minutes from a pandas column that has integer values in format HHMM, HMM, MM, and M?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains a column of data where each value is an integer meant to represent the hour and minute in a day. The problem is that each value does not follow the same format. If it is between 12:00 AM and 12:10 AM the value will just be one digit, the minute. If it is between 12:10 AM and 1:00 AM, the value will have to digits, again the minute. If it is between 1:00 AM and 10:00 AM, the value will have three digits, the hour and minute. Finally, for all other values (those between 10:00 AM and 12:00 AM, the value will have four digits, again the hour and minute.

I tried using the pandas, "to_datetime" function to operate on the whole column.

```
from pandas import read_csv, to_datetime
url = lambda year: f'ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/NOAA/G00807/IIP_{year}IcebergSeason.csv'
df = read_csv(url(2011))
def convert_float_column_to_int_column(df, *column_names):
    for column_name in column_names:
        try:
            df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype(int)
        except ValueError:
            df = df.dropna(subset=[column_name]).reset_index(drop=True)
            df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype(int)
    return df
df2 = convert_float_column_to_int_column(df, 'ICEBERG_NUMBER', 'SIGHTING_TIME')
df2['SIGHTING_TIME'] = to_datetime(df2['SIGHTING_TIME'].astype(str), format='%H%M')
```

The result I got was:

```
ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%H%M' (match).
```

Which was as expected.

I'm sure I could work around this problem by iterating through each row, using if statements, and converting each value to a four character string but these files are relatively big so that would be too slow of a solution.

Comment: Yes, that returns `ValueError: day is out of range for month`.

Comment: can you print `df2` or atleast a sample of it and an expected output. It will help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sure. This should cover all cases:

`import pandas as pd;`
`sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 10, 100, 1000]});`
`sample_df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df['B'].astype(str), format='%H%M')`

It produces the same error. What I'm looking for is a convenient way to know that the first value in B is meant to represent 12:01 AM. Then 12:10 AM, 1:00 AM, and 10:00 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for if statements. `Series.str.zfill` will pad it with the correct number of zeros to get it in the proper format. Then use `pd.to_datetime`, subtracting off 1900-01-01 which is the date it will use when none of those fields are present:

#### Input Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1, 12, 123, 1234]})
#   Time
#0     1
#1    12
#2   123
#3  1234
```

### `pd.to_datetime`

```
df['Time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.Time.astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%H%M') 
              - pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))

#0   00:01:00
#1   00:12:00
#2   01:23:00
#3   12:34:00
#Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

### `pd.to_timedelta`

Can also be used, but since you cannot specify a format parameter you need to clean everything beforehand:

```
df['Time'] = df.Time.astype(str).str.zfill(4)

# Pandas .str methods are slow, use a list comprehension to speed it up
#df['Time'] = df.Time.str[0:2] + ':' + df.Time.str[2:4] + ':00'    
csize=2
df['Time'] = [':'.join(x[i:i+csize] for i in range(0, len(x), csize))+':00' for x in df.Time.values]

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)

#0   00:01:00
#1   00:12:00
#2   01:23:00
#3   12:34:00
#Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: @evankielley Thanks! I updated it with a `pd.to_datetime` option, which I believe is probably more concise and performant. You just need to subtract off the dummy date